# dotnet restore Command not working in XUnit Project

Tags: .net-core

The below generates when executing **dotnet restore** command

D:\NewDotNetApp2>dotnet new xunit
Content generation time: 118.1211 ms
The template "xUnit Test Project" created successfully.

D:\NewDotNetApp2>dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for D:\NewDotNetApp2\NewDotNetApp2.csproj...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://
api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.\r [D:\NewDotNetApp2\NewDotNetApp2.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 40
7 (Proxy Authentication Required ( The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web
Proxy filter is denied.  )). [D:\NewDotNetApp2\NewDotNetApp2.csproj]

This just happening in XUnit Project all other projects like mvc,webapi etc are working file.

Please suggest what to do.

Comment: Do you maybe use a corporate NuGet proxy that only whitelists some packages?

Comment: but other projects successfully restore using `dotnet restore` command then what's wrong with XUnit?

Comment: Any NuGet.Config file in the project or on your machine that specifies a custom NuGet feed? `The ISA Server requires authorization` sounds like an infrastructure problem

Comment: No custom NuGet feed nor created NuGet.config in the project.....if I create NuGet.config file in the project what feed should I use to avoid error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is resolved after installing Microsoft Firewall Client  for ISA Server

Thanks Matin :)